# Visual C++ Express How do I set the default browser to view help files?

Tags: visual-c++

I don't know why anyone should have to ask this question, but clicking on help I get error saying that my recently installed VC++ express cannot show HELP because default browser not set.  Don't see any option to change this setting either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the same on Express, but on Ultimate it's under Tools->Options.

[image]